# I want to Display both of the cards on my About Component but i am not able to display both at a time

Tags: react-native

I need to display both cards in render(){return(...);} function but i only get output of one card; by commenting one of them cards they display very well, but did not displaying both cards at the same time.
what should i do ?

```
class AboutUs extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            leaders: LEADERS
        };
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'About Us'
    };


    render() {
        const renderLeader = ({item, index}) => {

            return (
                    <ListItem
                        key={index}
                        title={item.name}
                        subtitle={item.description}
                        hideChevron={true}
                        leftAvatar={{ source: require('./images/alberto.png')}}
                      />

            );
        }

        return (
             <Card title={'Our History'}>
                     <Text>
                         Hong Kong.  s.
                     </Text>

                     <Text>{"\n"}
                         The restaurant traces 
             </Card>,

            <Card title={'Corporate Leadership'}>
                <FlatList 
                    data={this.state.leaders}
                    renderItem={renderLeader}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                />
            </Card>
    );
    }
}

export default AboutUs;
```

Comment: One thing you could try, is to wrap the cards in a Fragment. React (and React Native) expects the `render()` method to return a single element, you're returning two elements. A solution could be to wrap it in `<Fragment></Fragment>` (or the shorthand version: `<> </>`)

Comment: did not work..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by wraping cards with ScrollView: thank you all for the suggestions

```
            <ScrollView>
                <Card title={'Our History'}>
                        <Text>
                            Started in 2010, 
                        </Text>
                        <Text>{"\n"}
                            The restaurant n.
                        </Text>
                </Card>

                <Card title={'Corporate Leadership'}>
                    <FlatList 
                        data={this.state.leaders}
                        renderItem={renderLeader}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                    />
                </Card>
            </ScrollView>  
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your component with something, I am using a React.Fragment below. Why are you using a comma?

```
  return (
    <>
     <Card title={'Our History'}>
      <Text>
         Hong Kong.  s.
      </Text>
     <Text>
        {"\n"}The restaurant traces 
     </Text>
     </Card>
     <Card title={'Corporate Leadership'}>
        <FlatList 
           data={this.state.leaders}
           renderItem={renderLeader}
           keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        />
     </Card>
    </>);
```

Comment: when i remove comma they give syntax error. I tried to wrap but did not work

Comment: Please put your code into a https://codesandbox.io/ and I can review it.

Comment: how can i upload code in codesandbox.. i did not use this before

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class AboutUs extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            leaders: LEADERS
        };
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'About Us'
    };


    render() {
        const renderLeader = ({item, index}) => {

            return (
                    <ListItem
                        key={index}
                        title={item.name}
                        subtitle={item.description}
                        hideChevron={true}
                        leftAvatar={{ source: require('./images/alberto.png')}}
                      />

            );
        }

        return (
             <>
             <Card title={'Our History'}>
                     <Text>
                         Hong Kong.  s.
                     </Text>

                     <Text>{"\n"}
                         The restaurant traces 
                     </Text>
             </Card>

            <Card title={'Corporate Leadership'}>
                <FlatList 
                    data={this.state.leaders}
                    renderItem={renderLeader}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                />
            </Card>
    </>);
    }
}

export default AboutUs;
```